# DateMember needed in models for Web API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Sometimes my models require me to decorate the properties with DataMember and other times not. Otherwise, the properties are null through web services. I have not figured out why or what the pattern of when to add the attribute and when not to. Is it when I have inherited models? Perhaps when I have models as properties of other models? When should I do this or should I always add the attribute on my properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataMember is useful when you want to use a different name for your property in the model to the value being sent in the request Payload. It basically gives you some control over the serialization.

For example:

```
[DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Also IIRC if you specify `DataMember` on one property you should specify it for all properties (even if you do not override the name) and also decorate your model with the `[DataContract]` attribute.

Comment: So if I decorate a base class with [DataContract], I guess I got to do that with all my derived classes.. just [DataContract] and [DataMember] with no options otherwise my ajax results have null properties.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty strange. Never happened to me. Could you share some repro steps (your view model and the exact payload sent to the Web API from the client)?

Comment: I just updated my last comment while you were writing, sorry. So you think it could be a base class forcing this [DataMember] requirement on the derived classes with no option?

Comment: No idea without a specific code sample to discuss. As I said, this never happened to me in the past.

Comment: I think your updated answer is right.. if you define DataMember on one property, you should do it for the rest. Thanks!